# How to remove brackets and the contents inside from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file named sample.txt which looks like below

```
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList[1].DefaultHandling=1
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList[1].ServiceInformation=
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList[1].IncludeRegisterRequest=n
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList[1].IncludeRegisterResponse=n
```

Here my requirement is to remove the brackets and the integer and enter os commands with that

```
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList.DefaultHandling=1
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList.ServiceInformation=
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList.IncludeRegisterRequest=n
ServiceProfile.SharediFCList.IncludeRegisterResponse=n
```

I am quite a newbie in Python. This is my first attempt. I have used these codes to remove the brackets:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import os
import sys
f = os.open("sample.txt", os.O_RDWR)
ret = os.read(f, 10000)
os.close(f)
print ret
var1 = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", ret)
print var1f = open("removed.cfg", "w+")
f.write(var1)
f.close()
```

After this using the file as input I want to form application specific commands which looks like this:

```
cmcli INS  "DefaultHandling=1 ServiceInformation="
```

and the next set as

```
cmcli INS "IncludeRegisterRequest=n IncludeRegisterRequest=y"
```

so basically now I want the all the output to be bunched to a set of two for me to execute the commands on the operating system.

Is there any way that I could bunch them up as set of two?

Comment: Only once you show your own code attempt and explain in a nicely packaged [mcve] where your difficulties lie. :)

Comment: Please share your working then we can make suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading 10,000 bytes of text into a string is really not necessary when your file is line-oriented text, and isn't scalable either. And you need a very good reason to be using `os.open()` instead of `open()`.

So, treat your data as the lines of text that it is, and every two lines, compose a single line of output.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

command = [None,None]
cmd_id = 1
bracket_re = re.compile(r".+\[\d\]\.(.+)")
# This doesn't just remove the brackets: what you actually seem to want is 
# to pick out everything after [1]. and ignore the rest.

with open("removed_cfg","w") as outfile:
    with open("sample.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            m = bracket_re.match(line)
            cmd_id = 1 - cmd_id  # gives 0, 1, 0, 1
            command[cmd_id] = m.group(1)

            if cmd_id == 1: # we have a pair
                output_line = """cmcli INS "{0} {1}" """.format(*command)
                print (output_line, file=outfile)
```

This gives the output

```
cmcli INS "DefaultHandling=1 ServiceInformation=" 
cmcli INS "IncludeRegisterRequest=n IncludeRegisterResponse=n"
```

The second line doesn't correspond to your sample output. I don't know how the input `IncludeRegisterResponse=n` is supposed to become the output `IncludeRegisterRequest=y`. I assume that's a mistake.

Note that this code depends on your input data being precisely as you describe it and has no error checking whatsoever. So if the format of the input is in reality more variable than that, then you will need to add some validation.